# JScrollPane and autoscroll: Disturbing scrolling behavior

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, autoscroll

I am writing an application which uses a JScrollPane. In this JScrollPane I want to automatically display search results, This means, that I have to dynamically add and remove the results within the JScrollPane. The results are realised as JTextArea, which are embeded within a GridBagLayout.

When there is a high number of search results, the JScrollPane automatically scrolls to the bottom (It should be at the top). I have solved it with a solution I found here. The problem hereby is, that you can see, how it scrolls back to the top. Is it possible to remove this behaviour?

The following things I found out:

- I have to remove the previous search results to display the new ones. If I don't remove the previous ones, it displays correctly.
- It neither solves the prblem wgeb I update the JScrollPane every tune after adding arow nor when updating only after adding all rows.

The best would be to just disable autoscroll. I have created an executable example to demonstrate this behavior. When clicking the button "Add Row", 500 rows are added. When clicking it several times, it becomes very clear.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ScrollPaneTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;


    /**
     * Creates new form ScrollPaneTest
     */
    public ScrollPaneTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new row.
     * @param index The index of the new row.
     */
    private void addRow(int index) {
        JTextArea row = new JTextArea("Area " + index);
        row.setEditable(false);
        row.setBorder(null);

        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = index;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 0, 2, 0);
        jPanel2.add(row, gridBagConstraints);
    }


    /**
     * Initializes the components.
     */
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
        jPanel1.add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        jButton1.setText("Create Rows");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(0, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                   

    /**
     * Creates 500 new rows.
     * @param evt
     */
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        jPanel2.removeAll();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            addRow(i);
        }

         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
            }

         });
         jPanel2.validate();
         jPanel2.repaint();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                new ScrollPaneTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }             
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I removed the lambda expressions. Hopefully it should be now compileable also with < Java 8.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem with the disturbing scrolling behavior has been solved by replacing

```
jPanel2.validate();
jPanel2.repaint();
```

with

```
jScrollPane1.validate();
jScrollPane1.repaint();
```

Nevertheless, both answers to this question can be very helpful in some other cases and should be given attention.

Comment: `you can see, how it scrolls back to the top.` - I can't because I don't use Java 8 and your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Dear camickr, I updated the code. Thank you for your interest and help!

Comment: Can't you just set the caret position to the start of the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to have a custom `JViewPort` for your scrollpane. This custom viewport overrides `setViewPosition` and uses a flag to prevent the scroll, or not.

Here is an example of such code, before changing the content of the textarea, we "lock" the viewport to prevent scrolling, and we unlock it later:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestNoScrolling {

    private int lineCount = 0;
    private LockableViewPort viewport;
    private JTextArea ta;

    private final class LockableViewPort extends JViewport {

        private boolean locked = false;

        @Override
        public void setViewPosition(Point p) {
            if (locked) {
                return;
            }
            super.setViewPosition(p);
        }

        public boolean isLocked() {
            return locked;
        }

        public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
            this.locked = locked;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        ta = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        viewport = new LockableViewPort();
        viewport.setView(ta);
        scrollpane.setViewport(viewport);
        frame.add(scrollpane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                viewport.setLocked(true);
                ta.append("Some new line " + lineCount++ + "\n");
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        viewport.setLocked(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestNoScrolling().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Guillaume Polet, this answer is really helpful! I built it into my example code and tried it a little bit. If i set  viewport.setView(jPanel1) it doesn't work. However, if I set viewport.setView(jPanel2) it does work! But like this, there is an other problem: For example, when there are only two searchResults (only two times addRow(i)), the results are displayed in the middle of the field and not at the top. The purpose of jPanel1 was, to place it at NORTH position. I tried it now with setting anchors in the GridBagConstraint's and others but it also doesn't help. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rolch2015 try setting `weighty = 1.0; anchor = NORTH` (simplified code).

Comment: Dear @Guillaume Polet, i also tried weighty = 1.0 and anchor. But like this, if i.e. there are only two rows, then it vertically stretches the rows so that they fill the whole field. Setting Preffered/Maximum etc. size of the row also doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Rolch2015 you need to set the fill attribute to NONE or HORIZONTAL: `gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;` or  `gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`

Comment: Dear @Guillaume Polet, that also doesn't work, because like this, there is a big gap between the first and the second row.

Comment: Dear @Guillaume Polet and MadProgrammer, after reading your answers, I just now experimented again a lot of time and by chance found the solution. If I validate and repaint instead of the JPanel the JScrollBar, the scrollbar doesn't have the disturbing behavior AND the rows display at the top, if there are only a few rows... . I am new to stackoverflow and don't know, how I should now mark the right answer? I found your answers both really helpful and think I can use them in the future. However, they didn't solve 100% this specific problem. I really appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply set the `Caret` position to the start position (`0`), for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ScrollNoMore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollNoMore ();
    }

    public ScrollNoMore () {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;
        private JScrollPane sp;
        private Random rnd = new Random();

        private boolean initalised = false;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
            add(sp);
            Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    long value = rnd.nextLong();
                    ta.append(String.valueOf(value) + "\n");
                    if (!initalised) {
                        ta.setCaretPosition(0);
                        initalised = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

This will only set it the first time the `Timer` runs, this means that if you move the `Caret` or scroll position for some reason, it won't "flick" back.  You could set up a series of states where by if the user moved the current view, it didn't effect the scrolling, but could be reset as required.

Comment: Dear @MadProgrammer, i also tried setCaretPosition(0) but it doesn't work, because I add dynamically JTextAreas to my Panel and don't have only one.

Comment: Dear @MadProgrammer, i have found the solution. Please look at the above comments to the first answer.

Comment: Okay, but the basic principle is still the same.  You know where you going to be adding text, so you must already have a reference to the `JTextArea` to be update. Just saying